# Data frame with different number of values for a column

Tags: r

Is it possible to create a data frame with the elements of a certain column containing different number of values?

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(A = letters[1:10], B = 1:10)
```

I'd like certain rows of column B to have 1, 2 or 3 elements, like:

```
df[2,2] <- list(c(1,2))
```

Or:

```
df[5,2] <- list(c(1:3))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can extract the column and do the assignment

```
df$B[2] <- list(c(1, 2))
df
#   A    B
#1  a    1
#2  b 1, 2
#3  c    3
#4  d    4
#5  e    5
#6  f    6
#7  g    7
#8  h    8
#9  i    9
#10 j   10
```

NOTE: This will convert the column to a `list` as `list` can have elements of different lengths/type

Comment: thanks @akrun, it works. just don't know why it doesn't with my notation

Comment: @NunoNogueira the assignment is still happening while subsetting the data.frame, it is still a data.frame.  instead of a vector causing the `warning`